# Looking for references describing the physical transmission of rhinoviruses and coronaviruses

Tags: common-cold, disease-transmission, influenza, epidemiology

I'm looking for reputable reference works that describe the physical aspects of how particles containing rhinoviruses and coronaviruses travel through the environment during disease transmission.  I'm also interested in articles that describe how to engineer an indoor environment to discourage person to person transmission, and how disease spreads in different kinds of office environments.

[This New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/world/asia/china-coronavirus-contain.html#transmission) is an example of the kind of information I'm looking for:

> Respiratory viruses like these can travel through the air, enveloped in tiny droplets that are produced when a sick person breathes, talks, coughs or sneezes. **These droplets fall to the ground within a few feet.... Coronaviruses like the Wuhan virus can travel only about six feet from the infected person** [emphasis mine].

However, I'd like to cite works by experts in this area, rather than popular media, as science reporters often get details wrong.

The reason I'm interested in this that I'm compiling arguments against open-office workspaces.  The idea that virus-laden droplets "fall to the ground within a few feet" implies that cubicle walls between workers would reduce the spread of these droplets into neighboring workspaces, thus inhibiting the spread of disease among coworkers.

I'd also appreciate articles about the flu, but I'm most interested in rhinoviruses and coronaviruses since the lack of available vaccines preempts rejoinders like "that's not an issue, just get the flu shot."